# Machine vision cameras with ROS drivers?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Apart from pointgrey cameras and their ROS driver, what other machine vision companies have ROS drivers available so they can be plugged into a ROS system right off the bat?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271227/machine-vision-cameras-with-ros-drivers?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2017-09-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [USB_Cam node](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) and others are compatible with 90% of USB webcams ever made, so you have plenty of choice.

I use the USB_Cam node in combination with the [Magewell HDMI capture device](http://www.magewell.com/usb-capture-hdmi). This allows you to capture video from any camera with a HDMI output, good if you need higher quality video.

What application are you looking into?

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-10-19**:
What kind of cameras are you using with hdmi outputs?  Do any have a way of controlling settings on the camera from the computer?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2017-11-29**:
We're using GoPos with this capture device. They are nice high quality cameras with a wide FOV which is ideal for our work. The downside is you can not control the camera in any way from the computer, the HDMI standard doesn't include this capability as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We ([magazino.eu](http://magazino.eu)) developed a driver for cameras from [Basler](https://www.baslerweb.com/en/): [pylon_camera](https://github.com/magazino/pylon_camera)

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-09-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1